# Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I insert json data to mySql database like this:

```
{
    "socialnetwork": {
        "twitter": "tw-u"
    },
    "information": {
        "country": "Cuba",
        "state": "Sancti Spiritus"
    },
    "settings": {
        "social-enable": "1"
    }
}
```

Now, I try to update `social-enable` value using `JSON_REPLACED` method like this:

```
$builder = $this->db->table('users');
$builder->where('id', 2)->set('information', "JSON_REPLACE(information, '$.settings.social-enable', '0')", false) ;
$builder->update();
```

In action I see this error:

```
Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 27.
```

How do can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [JSON Path Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-path-syntax)
>
> ... Names of keys must be double-quoted strings or valid ECMAScript
> identifiers (see [Identifier Names and Identifiers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6), in the ECMAScript
> Language Specification). ...

Try:

```PHP
... JSON_REPLACE(information, '$.settings."social-enable"', '0') ...
```

**UPDATE**

Try:

```
$builder->where('id', 2)->set('information', "JSON_REPLACE(information, '$.settings.\"social-enable\"', '0')", false);
```

Comment: Right, I add `"social-enable"` in my query like your solution but I see new syntax this error in my code: `syntax error, unexpected 'social' (T_STRING), expecting ')' `